# Get list of parent and child records with multiple entries with criteria - SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, parent-child

I have parent / child tables:

parent table:

### id | description

1  | Alexandra
2  | Natalia

child table:

### id | id_parent | description

1  |     1     | Programmer
2  |     1     | Surgery
3  |     2     | Programmer
4  |     2     | IT

How to return set of record according filters, like if we want to get all records with "Programmer" we would like to have set:

response table:

### id_parent | id_child | description (from child)

```
1     |    1     |  Programmer
2     |    3     |  Programmer
```

BUT if filter looks like: "Programmer" AND "Surgery", query MUST return only:

response table:

### id_parent | id_child | description (from child)

```
1     |    1     |  Programmer
1     |    2     |  Surgery
```

As you can see I also need some kind of "join" in order to "connect" description and code in child table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your current SQL query.

Comment: SELECT   distinct  Parent.ID, Child.ID, Child.ID_SpecMatrix
FROM     Parent
inner JOIN Child ON Parent.ID = Child.ID_Parent
where 
 1=1
 and Child.ID_SpecMatrix = 4
 and Child.ID_SpecMatrix = 5

Last "and" bring empty, because no child's records have both "4" and "5" code...
Child records can be duplicated, except for key.

Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
SELECT * FROM Child
WHERE id_specmatrix IN (4,5) AND
      Parent_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent.id FROM parent p
                    JOIN Child s1 ON s1.id_parent = p.id AND s1.id_specmatrix = 4
                    JOIN Child s2 ON s2.id_parent = p.id AND s2.id_specmatrix = 5)
```

Comment: Yep! Man, this works! Thanks a lot! The only question - how to make this flexible - parameters number could change and fields like "id_specmatrix" about 100... Anyway I appreciate, idea was right!

Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id_parent,
       t.id,
       t.description
  FROM CHILD t
  JOIN CHILD p ON p.id_parent = t.id_parent AND p.description = 'Programmer'
  JOIN CHILD s ON s.id_parent = t.id_parent AND s.description = 'Surgery'
```

Based on your SQL, you need to use:

```
  SELECT p.ID, 
         c.ID, 
         c.ID_SpecMatrix 
    FROM Parent p
    JOIN Child c ON p.ID = c.ID_Parent AND c.ID_SpecMatrix = 4
    JOIN Child c2 ON p.ID = c2.ID_Parent AND c2.ID_SpecMatrix = 5
GROUP BY p.ID, 
         c.ID, 
         c.ID_SpecMatrix
```

The key is JOINing additional copies of the CHILD table.  The `ID_parent` to ID links the records together; the AND filters that copy of the CHILD table to contain only rows where the `ID_SpecMatrix` matches your criteria.

The query needs to use dynamic SQL to be scalable to however many criteria you want to use.

Comment: Hi rexem,

Thank for your answer, but this not work. Please take a look at my next post / comments to Daniel's post. 

Appreciate,
Boris

Comment: @Boris: It's been corrected - I was using PARENT when it should've been CHILD, and the JOIN needed to be using the id_parent rather than ID.

Comment: Hi rexem. Thank you for patience, but still don't work. I can't put a big example here, system don't allow to post more than 600 symbols. My current query, work for 1 condition (I changed field names, but the same case):

SELECT   distinct  Parent.ID, Child.ID, Child.ID_SpecMatrix
FROM     Parent
inner JOIN Child ON Parent.ID = Child.ID_Parent
where 
 1=1
 and Child.ID_SpecMatrix = 4

So i need to add second "and Child.ID_SpecMatrix = 5", and it don't work, cause no child records have at the same time codes "4" and "5".

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: i.e. I need to find parent records with child ones who contain both of conditions - 4 & 5 (and probably more), and output parent & child.
Thanks.

Comment: rexem,

I really appreciate your efforts, but still problems - I just tried your query on my database - "wrong" records - with "ID_SpecMatrix" other than 4,5 were fetched in addition to "right" ones. I need child's records only with id_specmatrix =4 and =5 (whatever that were given in condition)... Perhaps this happens cause of 1st join?

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: and sure i use dynamic sql, but it becomes increasingly difficult to manage it :) there are more than 100 parameters..

Comment: @Boris: No, all the joins to the CHILD table are on the same id.

Comment: rexem,
If you still interested in, you could check/compare this with query that suggested Kosta (above). His sql works. But it very hard to figure out how to automate building such strings dynamically, depending on input parameters. I'm trying now idea of using 2 queries - 1-st selet with "standard" filters and define list (of id) of parent's records, then use 2nd query, add this list like primary filter like " and id in (..)" and then add list of child's conditions, like " and specmatrix in (...)". All queries constructed  in code behind - c#...

Thanks anyway,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from parent p
left join child c
on p.id = c.id_parent
where c.description = 'Programmer'
or c.description = 'Surgen'

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thank for you help, but this would not work. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I wanted to be brief.

so, if child will look like:
id_par, id_ch, descr
1, 1, prog
1, 2, surg
1, 3, surg
2, 4, prog
2, 5, surg
2, 6, surg
3, 7, it
3, 8, prog

if request child's "prog", we want:

parent_id, child_id, child_descr
1,1,prog
2,4,prog
3,8,prog

but if "prog" AND "surg":

parent_id, child_id, child_desc
1, 1, prog
1, 2, surg
1, 3, surg
2, 4, prog
2, 5, surg
2, 6, surg

records in child might be duplicated and we want them. Only child records with 
ALL conditions must be in output.

Thanks,
Boris